# Apache camel Testing Route

Tags: java, unit-testing, apache-camel

I have a spring boot application with camel. 
I have a java defined route. I am using selector in that.

```
 from("jms:Q1?selector=fruit='apple'").process(appleProcessor);
 from("jms:Q1?selector=fruit='orange'").process(orangeProcessor);
```

I want to write a test case where I need to validate if the selector worked properly and if the correct processor was invoked.

So how to mock the processor. Is it like mocking endpoint.

Or is it like mocking an object (the appleProcessor, defining its bean in a context configuration class)  and validating by:

```
Mockito.verify(appleProcessor, VerificationModeFactory.times(1)).process(Mockito.any());
```

In my test case I use the ProducerTemplate to send the msg, and my route is being invoked correctly.

Please help.

Answer (score -1):

I don't fully understand what you are trying to achieve. JMS selector **will** work correctly, This is (or should be) guaranteed by Camel's unit tests and Spring JMS unit tests.

If you want to ensure that the selector is working, you should create an integration test, publish some messages in the queue, check the queue **and** the processors. I don't think it will add any value.

Conversely, if you want to test that an **'apple'** message goes to `appleProcessor`, this is a unit test of your code. Your approach using ProducerTemplate is good. I think that the problem lies in the fact that your processor is the last step in the chain. You could refactor your routes:

```
from("jms:Q1?selector=fruit='apple'").to("direct:processApple");
from("direct:processApple").process(appleProcessor);

from("jms:Q1?selector=fruit='orange'").to("direct:processOrange")
from("direct:processOrange").process(orangeProcessor);
```

Now you can mock `direct:` endpoints and assert that they received the expected message count.

Unit testing each processor is another test, of course.

Comment: It's NOT advisable to refactor main code for the purpose of making it easy to test especially the way its suggested here to add one or more direct routes - unnecessary steps in between which may confuse those who later maintain it.

Comment: @nanosoft I agree with you in this specific case. I was trying to answer the question asked, but probably a deeper refactor was needed. I think that writing testable code is necessary, and sometimes there's need for boilerplate or unconventional pattern. Tested code is better than nicely written but untested code.